# Find query matches for a multi-row input

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

Basically I have a set of CSV that I want to search through using a key from outside the query area. The query data is arranged like:

```
| COLUMN L | COLUMN K |
|----------|----------|
| A,B,C,D  | 1        |
| E,F,G,H  | 2        |
| I,J,K    | 3        |
```

etc

What I have so far is

```
query(A1:L12,"Select L where K matches '(?:^|,)"&A13&"(?:,.*|$)'",-1)
```

So if `A13`'s value is `G`, `2` is returned.

This works fine and returns the correct row value where it matches `A13`, but what I actually want to do is for this to process a column of data and return results for each key (or A13 value), but I can't work out how to translate this into "arrayformula" format. I tried this:

```
query(A1:L12,"Select L where K matches '(?:^|,)"&A13:A24&"(?:,.*|$)'",-1)
```

But no luck.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. That looks a lot better

Comment: `r-googlesheets` is a package written for the R programming language (that works with data in Google Sheets), while `google-spreadsheet` is the tag related to the Google Sheets web application.